# Слайс байтов меняется сам по себе

Tags: golang

Реализую шифрование ГОСТ Р 34.12-2015, возникла проблема со слайсом байтов из исходного текста. В начале программы он имеет корректную форму, а уже после шифрования(вызываю функцию куда передаю исходный текст в виде байтового слайса) он имеет уже другое значение. Помогите, пожалуйста.

Привожу отрывок кода:

```
func main() {
    str := "Hello it's me, a Mario!!"
    text := []byte(str)

    keys := magmaExpandKey([]byte("asdfghjklz,cmvnfkwadmandksjtmdolasdasdf"))

    var crypted []byte

//Первый блок чисто для примера
    fmt.Printf("Original: %b\n", text[0:8])
    crypted = magmaEncrypt(text[0:8], keys)
    fmt.Printf("Original: %b\n", text[0:8])

/* Вывод:
Original: [1001000 1100101 1101100 1101100 1101111 100000 1101001 1110100]
Original: [1001000 1100101 1101100 1101100 11000011 1101001 11001110 1010111]
*/


    fmt.Printf("Crypted: %s\n", crypted)
    fmt.Printf("Decrypted: %s\n", magmaDecrypt(crypted, keys))
}

func magmaEncrypt(blk []byte, keys []roundKey) []byte {
    var crypted []byte

    // Преобразования G
    crypted = magmaG(keys[0].Key, blk)

    for i := 1; i < 31; i++ {
        crypted = magmaG(keys[i].Key, crypted)
    }

    // Последнее (тридцать второе) преобразование G
    crypted = magmaG(keys[31].Key, crypted)

    return crypted
}
```

Comment: Самостоятельный велосипединг реализации шифрования - плохая идея. Возьмите openssl.

Comment: покажите magmaG.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

я хотел написать, что исходя из кода `crypted = magmaG(keys[i].Key, crypted)`, когда передаете слайс, то передается не копия, а ссылка на этот слайс. я могу сделать предположение, что функция magmaG append-ит к crypted новое значение.

Однако, я загуглив magmaG я нашел кусок вашего примера

```
func magmaG(k []byte, a []byte) []byte {
    var left []byte
    var right []byte
    var G []byte
 
    // Делим 64-битный исходный блок на две части
    left = a[0:4]
    right = a[4:8]
 
    // Производим преобразование g
    G = magma_g(k, right)
 
    // Ксорим результат преобразования g с левой половиной блока
    G = magmaAddXor(left, G)
 
    // Пишем в левую половину значение из правой
    left = right
 
    // Пишем результат GOST_Magma_Add в правую половину блока
    right = G
 
    // Сводим правую и левую части блока в одно целое
    return append(left, right...)
}
```

очевидно, что внутри magmaG меняется `a`,  а эта переменная передается как слайс, а значит, меняется по ссылке.

чтобы пофиксить эту проблему, нужно внутри функции magmaG для переменных left и right инициализировать каждый элемент ( и желательно явно указать размер)

```
func magmaG(k []byte, a []byte) []byte {
    var left []byte = make([]byte, 4)
    var right []byte = make([]byte, 4)
    var G []byte

    // Делим 64-битный исходный блок на две части
    for i := 0; i < 4; i++ {
        left[i] = a[i]
    }
    var j int = 0
    for i := 4; i < 8; i++ {
        right[j] = a[i]
        j++
    }
```

Тогда результат будет

> Original: [1001000 1100101 1101100 1101100 1101111 100000 1101001
> 1110100] Original: [1001000 1100101 1101100 1101100 1101111 100000
> 1101001 1110100]

[ссылка на рабочий пример](https://play.golang.org/p/ZTYP1QCv-bo)